# Parts of a pdf file display strange characters on some computers

Tags: pdf

I'm looking for help for a problem one of our consultants has with a PDF file. I've looked for similar problems, but the closest one "Why do strange characters sometimes appear in PDFs on some computers?" is not exactly what I'm experiencing.

Most of the PDF pages of this document have been created from Adobe InDesign, among which the one which has a problem (see picture attached):

[image]

The PDF file is opened with a Polish program called Czytnik (Polish name but this is default application in Polish version of Microsoft) -
https://www.microsoft.com/pl-pl/store/apps/czytnik/9wzdncrfhwg5, but there is no problem when viewing it on his phones (Android and IOS) and Ipad.

I've checked if the font in the other InDesign pages was the same for the parts displaying strange characters, but it is the same, so the problem doesn't come from there.

His colleague in Poland doesn't have that problem, but I'm not sure he uses the same program to open PDF files... I'll check.

I've asked him to try opening the file with Adobe Reader or Foxit Reader, but I don't think he has tried.

Can you help?

Comment: Take a look, Regine, seems to be the same: http://helpdesk.win2pdf.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/173/3/pdf-files-are-displayed-with-random-characters

Comment: Thanks for this link, DavidPostill. I'll ask the consultant to make sure he views the pdf files with Adobe Reader and not the other program. His colleague has the same problem when viewing it with this Czytnik app, so the problem comes from there, but as the pdf is sent to clients and prospects, he is afraid they will have the same problem, as this app is the default application of Microsoft for viewing pdfs... I've told him to add a note when sending this file, telling the readers that the file is best viewed with Adobe Reader... If you have any other idea, they are welcome! Thanks.

Comment: I'm not DavidPostill but you are welcome, Regine ;)

Comment: Sorry duDE! :-)